# How to use MS Access expression builder for if fieldA value = " then fieldB = "

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2000, expressionbuilder

Using MS Access expression builder for if fieldA value = " then fieldBdate = "
table name is myOrder;
myOrder has several fields including fieldA text (using value list for value selection, of which "Received" is one);
And another field is named fieldBdate of DateTime type.

```
either
iif (fieldA] = "Received",[ fieldBDate] = Date(), null);
or 

if ([fieldA] = "Received" then[ fieldBdate] = Date()

failed to meet with Access expression syntax
```

with both Access 2000 and Access 2010.  What's the correct syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Time for you to learn how to use built-in VBA manual with Intellisense and even basic google search of IIf syntax

**How to use:**

```
IIF( <test-for-condition>, <value if true>, <value if false> )
```

**In your case:**

```
FieldBDate = IIf([FieldA] = "Received", Date(), Null)
```

**EDIT - Based upon your comment that you want to set Default Value**

You **cannot** set the Default Value expression based on another field in a table design. Think about it - there's no way that Access knows what the other field's value is until it's actually entered.

What you need to do is add the above code to your `FieldA_AfterUpdate` event

Comment: Informative and it's very logical.  However, with Access table design, and then, Default Value field (for the fieldB): either = IIf([FieldA] = "Received", Date(), Null)  or fieldB = IIf([FieldA] = "Received", Date(), Null) failed with the error msg to the event that Access does not recognize the field.  Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to use this with "Default Value"? You didn't think that was pertinent to the question? Maybe add this as well as actual field names and types to your question